# How can I use JQ to change a value in a nested array?

Tags: json, jq

I'd like to change a value in a JSON file.  Following is a snippet of the JSON document that shows the structure I'm trying to traverse:

```
{
  "panels": [
    {
      "panels": [
        {
          "alert": {
            "notifications": [
              {
                "uid": "dmRej73Gz"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I'd like to change**

I'd like to change the value for all **UIDs** inside of the **notifications** array to another value.

I have tried the following, with no success:

**cat MyJson.json | jq -r '.panels[] |.panels[].alert | .notifications[] | .uid |="newvalue"'**

```
{
  "uid": "newvalue"
}
```

**cat MyJson.json | jq -r '. | select(.panels[].panels[].alert.notifications[].uid="newvalue")'**

**(Note UID not changed at all)**

```
{
  "panels": [
    {
      "panels": [
        {
          "alert": {
            "notifications": [
              {
                "uid": "dmRej73Gz"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**This is what I'd actually like to see:**

```
{
  "panels": [
    {
      "panels": [
        {
          "alert": {
            "notifications": [
              {
                "uid": "newvalue"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Use Case**
I have Grafana dashboard that I am trying to incorporate into our CICD process.  One dashboard will be created in the Dev environment and then deployed to INT and PROD.

The only thing that changes from one environment to the next is the notification channel which is (unfortunately) represented as a UID.  I'm making a call to the destination Grafana site and getting the notification UID for the target environment.  This will be used as an argument to the JQ call I'm making (what was called **newvalue** above).  Then another JQ call will be made to change the dashboard UID.  Then I'll take this modified JSON and post it to the target Grafana environment using the Grafana API.

If all goes well the dashboard will be created with the notification channels intact and with a unique dashboard UID.  Hope that's not TMI. :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating:

```
jq '.panels[].panels[].alert.notifications[].uid |= "newvalue"'
```

You don't want to drill down and change `.` (the scope for what will eventually be output), so the *entire path from the top* should be on the left side of the `|=` operator, and you don't need any `|`. There's no need for the `-r` option either.

Comment: Thank you!  I've so used to using "-r" I wasn't aware I had in in there.  You're correct, is wasn't needed.  This works.  The thing I'm running into now is I'm getting the dreaded "Cannot iterate over null (null)" error when I apply this to the entire(real) json document.  It could be that one of the Alerts objects is missing the Notifications array.  I know you can check for the array length using Select, but I'm not sure if it's available with the format I'm using.

Comment: @KSS in that case you can try 0stone0's solution, or you can try replacing all of the `[]` with `[]?` which will ignore nulls instead of attempting to treat them as arrays.

Comment: This works! ".panels[].panels[]?.alert.notifications[]?.uid |= "newvalue"" - Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [@hobbs solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67693664/5625547) where we use [`walk()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example65) to change **literally all the `.uid` values** so we don't have to define the full path:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("uid") then .uid = "NEW VALUE" else . end)
```

[JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AZwsxMxNRl)

---

Also, to remove the [unnecessary `cat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16279/should-i-care-about-unnecessary-cats) we can pass the file to JQ itself:

```sh
jq 'walk(if type == "object" and has("uid") then .uid = "NEW VALUE" else . end)' MyJson.json
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It works perfectly.  But is changes ALL the UIDs and it looks like walk doesn't allow you to specify a particular path to begin the walk.  However, for what I'm trying to do it may be fine.  All the Notification UIDs change and the only other UID is the UID for the dashboard itself.  As it happens, I need to change that UID as well, so it would be a simple matter to do one more edit and change the dashboard UID.  This might be the solution.

Comment: Glad it helped! Could you perhaps give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I just added a Use Case section to the original post.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Understand your usecase, but having a hard time imagining the JSON and how you would like to format it.

Comment: No formatted needed.  It is generated by Grafana, all I'm doing is changing some of its values.